# minlength validator not working, angular6 reactive form

Tags: angular

I am trying using minlength validator like this

```
<mat-error  *ngIf="peAddForm.controls.peBundleId.hasError('minlength') && (peAddForm.controls.peBundleId.dirty || peAddForm.controls.peBundleId.touched)">
                                Minimum value should be 1
```

But is is not showing error.

Please help

EDIT:  I got the answer, it should be 'min' not 'minlength'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
*ngIf="peAddForm.controls.peBundleId.errors?.minlength
```